# iptables block fragmented flow that contain specific string

Tags: linux, shell, security, iptables

I want to block traffic that contain specific string `"anypattern"`.

I know that the right iptables rule for that is:

```
iptables -m string --algo bm --string "anypattern" -j DROP
```

The problem that the data could be split to many TCP sequences. And there is a risk that the string `"anypattern"` could be split in 2 packets. For example the packet 1 will contains `"anyp"` and the second packet will contains `"attern"`

How I can make iptables detect TCP fragmentation and make the check on the final tcp payload?
Or are there a solution for such issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think netfilter string extension is not the right tool do to this safely.
I understand that it looks very comfortable to have string detection with good old iptables, but if you want more solid results i think you need to switch to a dedicated application layer IDS (Es. [Suricata](https://suricata-ids.org/))